# What goes wrong when students interchange "there exists" and "for all" randomly? How to fix this?

Tags: undergraduate-education, logic, students-mistakes

I think, it is a very common problem that some students have huge problems with definitions when there appears a quantification.

Some examples:

- *Of course the sequence is bounded, because every part of the sequence is a real number and this real number is bounded by itself.*
- *Look, here is a finite covering for this set, hence it is compact.*
- A lot more examples related to $\delta$-$\epsilon$ criterion, etc.
- Also, many students don't quantify new introduced variables which leads then to bigger problems during their proofs.

**What goes wrong if students interchange (or leave open) the quantification in the definitions? How can this be fixed or at least improved?**

Comment: You're asking about all student confusion related to interchanging quantifiers? There is a lot of work in this area; plenty is easily found through google scholar. What specific scenario are you concerned about and what have you already found in the literature?

Comment: You should **never** explain this with "every student has a mother" sort of analogy. These analogies will only confuse people further. We had an exam question to explain the difference between two such statements without a rigorous proof. The answers were almost all half-assed explanations "Uhh... every pot has a lid, but there is no one lid for all the pots so.. uhh.."; stick to definitions and explain to students that they should also verify their intuition with a step-by-step analysis from the definitions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way to increase awareness of this issue is to explore what happens if the quantors are changed from exists to for all, and vice versa.

On math.SE, there was a [question which dealt precisely with this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/683590/a-game-with-delta-epsilon-and-uniform-continuity)

The following exercise is supposedly from Makarov's *Selected Problems in Real Analysis*:

> Describe the set of functions $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ having the following properties ($\epsilon, \delta,x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb R$) :
>
> a) $\forall \epsilon ,\qquad\qquad \exists \delta>0 ,\qquad |x_1-x_2| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x_1)-f(x_2)|<\epsilon$
>
> b) $\forall \epsilon >0 ,\qquad \exists \delta ,\qquad \qquad |x_1-x_2| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x_1)-f(x_2)|<\epsilon$
>
> c) $\forall \epsilon >0 ,\qquad \exists \delta>0 ,\qquad (x_1-x_2) < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x_1)-f(x_2)|<\epsilon$
>
> d) $\forall \epsilon >0 ,\qquad \forall \delta>0 ,\qquad |x_1-x_2| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x_1)-f(x_2)|<\epsilon$
>
> e) $\forall \epsilon >0 ,\qquad \exists \delta>0 ,\qquad |x_1-x_2| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x_1)-f(x_2)|>\epsilon$
>
> f) $\forall \epsilon >0 ,\qquad \exists \delta>0 ,\qquad |x_1-x_2| < \epsilon \Rightarrow |f(x_1)-f(x_2)|<\delta$
>
> g) $\forall \epsilon >0 ,\qquad \exists \delta>0 ,\qquad |f(x_1)-f(x_2)| > \epsilon \Rightarrow |x_1-x_2|> \delta$
>
> h)  $\exists \epsilon >0 ,\qquad \forall \delta>0 ,\qquad |x_1-x_2| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x_1)-f(x_2)|<\epsilon$
>
> i)  $\forall \epsilon >0 ,\qquad \exists \delta>0 ,\qquad x_1-x_2 < \delta \Rightarrow f(x_1)-f(x_2)<\epsilon$

Comment: Nice exercise! +1

Comment: The omission of the quantifiers for $x_1$ and $x_2$ is rather unfortunate.

Comment: @Gilles: Indeed, it is. However, I kept it this way since it was originally posted like this.